# Get local IP on angular2 component.ts

Tags: angular, web, ip

I have a web app and an API inside a raspberry PI. The web app uses HTTP GET requisitions to the API to display its content

Now, inside the web app component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    results = {};

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    ngOnInit(): void {

        var url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';
        var endpoint = 'test/';

        this.http.get(url + endpoint).subscribe(data => {
          this.results = data['test'];
        })
    }
}
```

This works when I open the web app on a browser INSIDE the raspberry. 
However, when opening the web app from another device using the raspberry's IP and the port the app is running, I can't get the data from the API.

I assume it's because of the 'localhost', and once this rasp CANNOT BE SET WITH A STATIC IP I'd like to retrieve its local IP, to make something like:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {

        var ip = <some code <-- HELP>
        var url = 'http://' + ip + ':8000/api/';
        var endpoint = 'test/';

        this.http.get(url + endpoint).subscribe(data => {
          this.results = data['test'];
        })
    }
```

And I've tested, if I put the IP manually in the code it works, though it was just for test, I don't want to input it manually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the `origin` by `window.location.origin`. For more details check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

    var ip = window.location.origin // this will give you the ip:port
    //if you just want the ip or hostname you can use window.location.hostname
    var url =  ip + '/api/';
    var endpoint = 'test/';

    this.http.get(url + endpoint).subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data['test'];
    })
}
```

Comment: That would be awesome if the port didn't come along with it. The API is running on port 8000, but I'll try to make it as a string and cut it short. Maybe that works?
Thank you anyway :)

Comment: well if you just want the `ip` or `hostname` I mean without the `port` you can use `window.location.hostname`

Comment: you can see all the properties of `window.location` on the link I mentioned in the answer

Comment: and don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helps :p

Comment: I'm sorry I did not see that link! Really didn't, I don't even know why. I guess I was so tired it slipped by. I did use a workaround using string manipulation just to get it working and continue the project but I'll now implement the correct way :) thank you very very much. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: I am running local.. i get error.. http://localhost:4444/api/test/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, I get localhost, but not my actual IP address. How do I get my actual/network's IP address?

Comment: window.location.origin doesn't give the IP....This returns localhost:port in development environment and the hostname in production environment.

Comment: @Ziggler, make sure you've defined the related end point on backend side

Comment: @JulianCorrêa, yes you are right. That's what I've described above.