# Angular 5, Getting actual network IP Address

Tags: angular, clientip

Hi Angular 2/5/6 Gurus,

I was trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208629/get-local-ip-on-angular2-component-ts), to get my machine's network IP address. But I got "localhost" as an IP address instead. I was expecting the result for this one to be like 10.0.5.21 for example.

Is there anyway I can get this?

Heaps of thanks to you guys!
Artanis Zeratul

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `https://jsonip.com`

```
this.http.get('https://jsonip.com/').subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without pinging an external server?